# Is ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ThreadSafe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm using C# with .net 4.0

Is ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem thread safe?

Example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(commands, commandModel =>
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TestService.ProcessTest, test.ID);
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you are worried about that could happen.

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads just to queue work up in the ThreadPool? Why aren't you just using a regular foreach loop?

Comment: @BFree, maybe there are very many work items and they can be enqueued in parallel as well, although I don't know if this will in practice be any faster because the queue is most likely synchronized at some point?

Comment: What do you mean by "thread safe" in this context

Comment: What's the point of using Parallel.ForEach to queue up work in thread pools?  The loop iterations of the Parallel.ForEach are already running in parallel threads!  Your code is like making a long distance phone call to your grandmother to ask her to call someone else long distance.

Comment: In general, every static method in the .NET framework is thread-safe (unless stated otherwise, but I can't think of one). `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is static, thus thread-safe.

Comment: It would be a pretty poor ThreadPool if you could not queue items onto it concurrently... Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function itself is thread safe, the item you are queing on the other hand needs to do whatever it does with thread safety in mind.

Comment: Adding to your response, the class itself is thread safe. Being a static class, all the static functions on it are thread safe.